# Targeting names in an object to create a drop down

Tags: jquery, json, dom, iteration

I'm trying to create a drop down of the 50 states from an object that contains the state names as attributes. Example below:

```
window.LGMaps.maps.usa = {
    "paths": [
        {
            "enable": true,
            "name": "Alabama",
            "abbreviation": "AL",
            "textX": 657,
            "textY": 405,
            "color": "#5b9fbb",
            "hoverColor": "#12407e",
            "selectedColor": "#d12229",
            "url": "http://www.uskoreacouncil.org/",
            "text": "<h1>Alabama</h1><br /><h3>Goods Exported to Korea</h3><li>Top Category: Motor Vehicles</li> <li>Total Exports: 526,379,126</li> <h3>Services Exported to Korea</h3> <li>Top Category: Travel</li><li>Total Exports: 165,827,003</li><h3>Jobs Tied to Goods/Services</h3><li>Goods Related: 2,455</li><li>Services Related: 1,363</li>",
            "path": "M 631.30647,460.41572 L 629.81587,446.09422 L 627.06763,427.34158 L 627.22929,413.27709 L 628.03759,382.23824 L 627.87593,365.58718 L 628.04102,359.16812 L 672.5255,355.54867 L 672.3777,357.73109 L 672.53936,359.83269 L 673.18601,363.22756 L 676.58089,371.14893 L 679.00579,381.01024 L 680.46074,387.15335 L 682.07734,392.00317 L 683.5323,398.95458 L 685.63388,405.25934 L 688.22045,408.65423 L 688.70543,412.04909 L 690.64537,412.8574 L 690.80703,414.95899 L 689.02875,419.80881 L 688.54377,423.04203 L 688.38211,424.98195 L 689.99873,429.3468 L 690.32205,434.68159 L 689.51373,437.10651 L 690.16039,437.91481 L 691.61533,438.72311 L 691.94347,441.61193 L 686.34581,441.25838 L 679.55606,441.90503 L 654.01366,444.81491 L 643.6021,446.22168 L 643.38072,449.09908 L 645.15899,450.87735 L 647.74556,452.81727 L 648.32642,460.75271 L 642.78436,463.32561 L 640.03614,463.00229 L 642.78436,461.06236 L 642.78436,460.0924 L 639.71282,454.11096 L 637.44957,453.46432 L 635.99462,457.82915 L 634.70134,460.57738 L 634.0547,460.41572 L 631.30647,460.41572 z"
        },
```

I was attempting to do this with the `.each()` jQuery method but I'm struggling to get the states to populate in a dropdown menu.

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
      <select>
        <option>Select a State</option>
        <option class="state"> </option>
      <select>
    </div>

function list_states(){
    var states = window.LGMaps.maps.usa.paths.name;
    $(".container .dropdown").text(states).each();
};
```

I'm looking to figure out how to get all of the states and iterate through them in my dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to note:

- in your example, `window.LGMaps.maps.usa` causes an error, as "we"
  don't have the nested object-structure available; maybe you do, in
  which case this should work for you as desired
- the [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`$.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) in jQuery are quite different, in that `$(selector).each()` iterates over a collection of
  jQuery objects, and `$.each()` is a general iterator-function. You don't **have** to use jQuery to iterate over an object/array: you can use a simple for-loop, bearing in mind this might dredge up junk from the prototype chain when accessing properties, especially such as `name`; using jQuery is quite alright, though.

```js
window.states = {
  paths: [{ name: "Alabama" }, { name: "Arkansas" }]
};

function list_states() {
  var states = window.states;
  $.each(states.paths, function(index, state){
    $('.container select').append('<option>' + state.name + '</option>');
  });
};

list_states();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <select>
        <option>Select a State</option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

Since your usage of jQuery in your question suggests you are not too familiar with it, I will not provide an answer that will leave you with more bewildered than enlightened, so perhaps the only "improvement" I would suggest is to avoid assigning to `window`, and avoid calling that little function explicitly:

```
$(function() {
  // this function executes as soon as the DOM is ready; it has the same effect as $(document).ready(function() {...});

  // this variable is not visible outside of the closure, i.e. it is not assigned to the global window object
  var states = { paths: [{ name: "Alabama" }, { name: "Arkansas" }] };

  $.each(states.paths, function(index, state) {
    $(".container select").append("<option>" + state.name + "</option>");
  });
});
```